# How to efficiently load an object model from a data store?

Tags: c#, oop

Consider if you will, the example of an `Order` class having a collection property of `OrderLines`.

```
public class Order
{
    public OrderLineCollection OrderLines { get; private set; }
}
```

Now consider a Data Access Layer that returns a collection of `Order` objects without the `OrderLines` property populated (empty collection).

To minimize round trips to the server, the system passes the ids of the all Order objects to the DAL, which returns the `OrderLine` objects for each Order in one go. Code in the Business Rules Layer is responsible for adding the correct `OrderLine` objects to the correct `Order` objects.

```
public class OrderDAL
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<OrderLine> GetOrderLines(IEnumerable<int> orderIds)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this general way of doing this kind of thing (to reduce database round-trips)?

Should the DAL have the responsibility of returning fully populated `Order` objects?

Are there better ways?

And no, I cannot use a ORM tool in this particular instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I for one don't. I don't want to go back to the store to retrieve more data after an initial query. When loading the data, you (ought to) know for what environment you are loading it, so you will know what "navigational properties" or joins you want to make on beforehand. This way with one query you can get all the data you want.

This is however from a stateless point of view, as I'm currently focusing on MVC and Entity Framework. I guess if you're creating an accounting program, you may have one Orders screen that displays order headers, and an Order Details screen where you want to display the details for the selected order. So in that case, yes, it can be useful to only have to retrieve the OrderLines for the selected order(s).

As usual, the answer is: it depends.

> And no, I cannot use a ORM tool in this particular instance!

Why?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot use an ORM tool because I am just extending some legacy classes. To introduce an ORM tool would require a greater investment of time than is permitted by management :(